# how to save the correct rotation of the Bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, kotlin, android-glide

I've this problem: when I load the photo that I've get from camera or, gallery, with this code:

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_PICK_PHOTO)
        //dalla fotocamera
        {
            if (data != null)mMediaUri = data.getData();

            Glide.with(this).load(mMediaUri).bitmapTransform(new CenterCrop(context), new RoundCornerTransformation(context, 15, 2)).into(photo);
        }
}
```

the picture is shown in the correct way in the imageView. 
Otherwise, I need to compress the bitmap so I've made this code to do the compression:

```
 fun compressBitmapInBackgroundtoByteArray(uri: Uri?,context: Context, callback: OnFinishedCallback) {

    Observable.create<ByteArray> { s ->


        var imageStream: InputStream? = null
        try {
            imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)
        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {
            s.onError(e)
        }

        val bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream)

        var stream: ByteArrayOutputStream? = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, stream)
        bmp.recycle()
        val compressed:ByteArray? =(stream?.toByteArray())

        try {
            stream?.close()

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            s.onError(e)
        }

        s.onNext(compressed!!)
        s.onComplete()

    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeBy (
                    onNext = { compress -> callback.onNext(compress) },
                    onError =  { error-> callback.onError(error.message) },
                    onComplete = { callback.onCompleted() }
            )


}
```

and this loose the correct orientation. In fact, when I try to load the byteArray I've given, with this code:

```
  if(user.getPicUrl() != null) {
        Glide.with(this).load(user.getPicture()).bitmapTransform(new CenterCrop(context), new RoundCornerTransformation(context, 15, 2)).into(photo);
        PICTURE_INSERTED = true;
    }
```

the picture has the rotation of 90 degrees. 
I've read that Glide supports Exif rotation, but in this case it doesn't work. Why? There is a way to "store" the correct orientation to save in the server? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You must copy the EXIF data from the original image to the final resized image.You can use ExifInterface for this.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html#ExifInterface

For example;

```
val oldExif = ExifInterface(oldImagePath)
val exifOrientation = oldExif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION)

if (exifOrientation != null) {
 val newExif = ExifInterface(imagePath)
 newExif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, exifOrientation)
 newExif.saveAttributes()
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor
Maybe this library helps you.Its min sdk 14.

Comment: I'm look at the ExifInterface now.Its support even API 5.Probably your import is wrong.My import like this : import android.media.ExifInterface